# I am trying to access both of my 2TB HDD's and find this error

Tags: mount, hard-drive

When I go to the files folder on my Ubuntu 16.04 dash, I get this error on both drives:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/rod/Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS amd64: 
    Command-line `mount -t "iso9660" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500" "/dev/sda2" "/media/rod/Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS amd64"' 
exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

I can still boot to Ubuntu without a problem, but I wish to use the second drive to reinstall Windows 7.  Being unable to get in to it I can do nothing. Has anyone out there experienced this problem?

Comment: Why would you want to mount this disk if you're going to install an unsupported version of Microsoft Windows? What is the output of `sudo lsblk` and `cat /etc/fstab`?

Comment: This notice will show up if your partition uses a microsoft format and the helper is not installed. You need ntfs tools to support ntfs. Same for exFat.

Comment: Hi to you both, I realise the Win7 is old but I bought it when new and as I really hate Windows I don't want to purchase a new version.

Comment: For some reason I can't put both answers on the one comment, it says 755 chars. too many, so I'll try 1 at a a time   sudo lsblk
 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0   976M  0 part 
├─sdb1   8:17   0 372.5G  0 part 
└─sdb6   8:22   0   1.5T  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sda      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   976M  0 part /boot
├─sda1   8:1    0 372.5G  0 part /
└─sda6   8:6    0   1.5T  0 part

Comment: # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=eaad9348-78c4-43cf-9798-1a57754b1eb3 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=0569c07e-b9a5-47e8-97bf-a92fc77e4ba4 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=1bd913de-8205-4052-9af8-3243dbe01e63 none            swap    sw              0       0